# Should I be using a SQLite db for my Android app or just JSON?

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

I'm currently building my first Android app and I've gotten to the point where i need to think about data storage. My app is built to assist in the drafting of a fantasy football team so it uses a large roster of 200-400 players each with individual projections, names, positions, teams, etc.

Though the app is sufficient to edit, add, and delete players and projections from rosters it definitely is not built to create a roster from the ground up so i'm going to include a default roster with the app. I would like users to be able to save and load the modifications they make to the default roster as well as download updated projections from online.

The only experience I have with databases is a remote MySQL db used in a web programming class. Is a DB appropriate for what I'm trying to do? Is there a way to store different versions of a database/table so users can have multiple rosters or download updates? Is this a better job for just a serialized JSON object?  Or both?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks guys

Comment: I would imagine user getting the data from the server as a JSON then storing and manipulating the data in SQL.

Comment: You wouldn't have different versions of a db or table to store multiple rosters, you'd create a proper relational model that associates a roster to roster members.

Comment: Just to be clear because I'm new to databases... are you suggesting that one of my columns will indicate which specific roster a certain player should be associated with? And that I would have a single table(or set of tables) which stores player info for multiple rosters? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your data is trivial, using Sqlite (Android's default DB engine) is the recommended storage approach for structured data.

JSON is useful for exchanging data with a server.